# Simplification of the Erdos-Gallai Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

A week or two ago back I was pointed to the [Erdos-Gallai Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32387/does-there-exist-a-general-graph-for-any-degree-sequence-of-even-natural-numbers).

I've been unable to locate a satisfactory proof of this theorem, since the reference on wikipedia is in Hungarian. I'm particularly curious to see the proof of just one direction.

Suppose you are already given that a degree sequence $(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ is graphic. How could you then show
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k d_i\leq k(k-1)+\sum_{i=k+1}^n\min(k,d_i)?
$$
A suggestion I read said to think about any set $U$ of $k$ vertices, and then consider how many edges have at least one end vertex in that set $U$. My guess is $k$, one connected to each vertex in $U$, but I don't see how that is very insightful. Is there a nice way of showing the above implication.

Comment: Shouldn't that $d_k$ on the left side of the display be $d_i$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 3-4 of Blitzstein and Diaconis's paper ["A Sequential Importance Sampling Algorithm For Generating Random Graphs With Prescribed Degrees"](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~blitz/BlitzsteinDiaconisGraphAlgorithm.pdf) has a brief discussion.

Quoting from the paper:

> The necessity of these conditions is not hard to see: for any set $S$ of $k$ vertices in a realization of $d$, there are at most $\binom{k}{2}$ "internal" edges within $S$, and for each vertex $v \notin S$, there are at most $\min(k, \deg(v))$ edges from $v$ into $S$.  The sufficiency of the Erdos-Gallai conditions is more difficult to show....

From their paper, they give a reference to:

- Berge, C. (1976). Graphs and Hypergraphs, Elsevier, New York.
- Choudum, S. A. (1986). A simple proof of the Erdos-Gallai theorem on graph sequences. Bulll. Austral. Math. Soc. 33, 1, 67-70 ([pdf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEcQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjournals.cambridge.org%2Fproduction%2Faction%2FcjoGetFulltext%3Ffulltextid%3D4740548&rct=j&q=choudum%20a%20simple%20proof%20erdos%20gallai&ei=9reuTe_pBYyjtgeF1qjdAw&usg=AFQjCNHK7fyIHUHC1W5i_d8GxzAc6TCQHQ&cad=rja))
- Tripathi, A. and Vijay, S. (2003). A note on a theorem of Erdos & Gallai. Discrete Math. 265, 1-3, 417-420

and of course the original paper that you found in hungarian:

- Erdos, P. and Gallai, T. (1960). Graphen mit punkten vorgeshriebenen grades. Math. Lapok 11, 264-274.

Searching around I also found a short paper by Tripathi, Venugopalan and West [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=5736EA4D33B86CDB7C027C985B57A1A7?doi=10.1.1.157.8267&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Hope that helps.